# How to alternate between two HTTP Requests in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Is there an easy way to get JMeter to alternate between two HTTP Requests in my test plan?
What's happening now is I have 8 threads (users) in my test.  I want to have 4 users hit HTTP A and 4 to hit HTTP B.  I put the HTTP Reqs in an Interleave Controller but that doesn't seem to do what I want.  It's only hitting HTTP A.  It only hits HTTP B when I set loop count = 2 and it goes thru iteratively, meaning loop = 1, all 8 threads hit HTTP A.  Loop = 2, all 8 threads hit HTTP B.  It doesn't alternate like I want.

I also looked at the Switch Controller but I don't know how to change the value or tell the controller which HTTP request to hit.

Can someone give me a hint on what I should do?  I have a simple test plan created so if someone needs me to post something, I can do it.  Just let me know.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this!

Use If Controller.

For my below setup - HTTP Request A would be called by the first 4 threads, Threads 5,6,7 & 8 would call HTTP Request B

[image]

EDIT:

Parameterize the total no of users for the test.

[image]

Then your If condition will change like this.

[image]

Comment: cool thx for looking and answering my question.  i've upvoted your answer but i can't select as the best yet b/c i'm sure i'll need to be able to increase the # of threads and I don't want to change the condition in the If controller every time.

Comment: Check the 'EDIT' - Please share if you find some other solution. Eager to learn.

Comment: @vlns, nothing new.  I just took your idea and did something similar:  ${__threadNum} % 4 == 1 or 0 in the 2nd if statement.  it seems to be working for me.  thx for your answer  =)

Answer (score 0):

There is one way out which may be if you can run two instances of Jmeter for Http request A and B respectively.Also check if code can reach B by just running Http Request B.